# Protractor - Storing a value for later use

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, end-to-end

Is there a way to save a value taken from one tests to use it later in another test in protractor. This is a odd case where, i need to read a cookie from the browser only once and have it available for all the spec files i am using in the tests. Reading it in the `beforeAll` method in each of the spec files is not the solution for me.

For example if i have 5 spec files and when i run the 1st spec file i get the cookie from the browser and the when that cookie information is needed in the following spec files i need to have it available. Is there a way to save this value so it is available for all the spec files? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onPrepare` in protractor's config file to execute some code once before all the tests ([example](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/withLoginConf.js)).

Keep in mind that you'll have to load a page of your application before being able to use [`getCookie`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.Options.prototype.getCookie).